# Payload content length greater than maximum allowed: 1048576 - Axios (Electron) and nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, electron

I'm requesting my node API server from my Electron app and I got this error :

```
body: '{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Payload content length greater than maximum allowed: 1048576"}'
```

I send Base 64 encoded images. With Http-client from my Angular website, the request works well, but with Axios (Electron), it doesn't work.

```
 updateUser: function(user, callback) {
      axios.post(environnement.urlServer+'update-user', {
        user: user
      })
      .then((response) => {
        callback(response.data);
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
```

My node server got limitation increased :

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "100mb", extended: true}))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "100mb", extended: true}))
```

I tried many things but I didn't find a solution.